# How to correctly install MEGASync for Pop-os 22.04 so it does not crash?

Tags: software-installation, crash, pop-os, cloud

I am runnign Pop-os 22.4 LTS. Recently my MEGASync app would crash when I would drop the menu to show what it is uploading and downloading. The app gives me the following error message (link below). I have tried:

- Removing the package and installing again the Ubuntu 22.04 megasync package from the official [mega website](https://mega.io/fr/desktop#downloadapps);
- Removing the software package and installing the Debian 10.0 megasync package.

I couldn't install the Debian package as it would tell me libraw19 is not installed on the system. I could not find libraw19 via apt or apt-get. Maybe there's another way to install it, yet I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do as I have never had to install that before.

Here's [the error message](https://codeshare.io/4e8b8b) from the Ubuntu installation, after the app crashes:

I don't really understand what has changed, could you please help me understand and fixing it? Thank you very much.

Comment: The linked error message shows a segmentation violation in the libmediainfo shared library. A segmentation violation implies that it is trying to read or write to memory that the OS does not allow it to access, or put it another way a bug. Reinstalling libmediainfo might fix it if the cause is corruption of some data associated with the package. Given that libmediainfo attempts to get information about media files, it might be that one of the files you are trying to sync is the cause of the issue, in which case the reinstall will not help.